# Doctrine ManyToMany and findBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried:

```
$task = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $id,'active' => true, 'assignedTo' => $this->getUser()]);
```

assignedTo is many to many field with User entity but i can't  filter like this, how to solve this trying avoid using query builder?

Comment: if assignedTo is mapped by a ManyToMany relation, then assignedTo is an ArrayCollection and I don't know what is doing doctrine in this case (error or just no filter) but you can't say : WHERE assignedTo = User. Because assignedTo is not the same type as $this->getUser() which is a simple entity

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write a query for this one. Something like this:

```
SELECT e1, e2 FROM Bundle:Entity1 e1 JOIN e1.assignedTo e2 WHERE e2 = :user
```

Does it work like this?

Comment: It should but more responsive is by findBy - i had a serializer configured.